# Frame navigation with key binding command?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I’d like to load a page into frame with key binding using ‘Ctrl’ and ‘H’ buttons from a keyboard. I can load page. It is working now. I am wondering if I can just override UriSource link with what it is now into frame. I assign UriSources in XML and I need to override one instance instead of introducing new UriSource to keep the index not changed. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static RoutedUICommand LoadShareSelectedCommand = new RoutedUICommand();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(LoadShareSelectedCommand, LoadShareSelectedCommandExecuted));
        KeyGesture kg = new KeyGesture(Key.H, ModifierKeys.Control);
        InputBinding ib = new InputBinding(LoadShareSelectedCommand, kg);
        this.InputBindings.Add(ib);
    }

    private void LoadShareSelectedCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContentFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/SharesSelected.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

    }

    private void LoadShareSelectedCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }


    private void NavShareSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContentFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/SharesSelected.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```